# Xpages - control spacing of bottom pager in a view

Tags: xpages

I have some views that I have built that are fairly basic, and I am trying to make them very aesthetically pleasing.

All has gone well except I cannot control the padding on the bottom pager.

I want there to be some space after the last entry and before the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your XPage's css

```
.xspDataTable {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```